# Save data to appropriate python data types through html form?

Tags: python, html, dictionary

I'm trying to build a flask app that will deploy one of my machine learning models.

I'm absolutely novice in HTML but through referring some templates and sample documents, I've been able to design a nice looking simple HTML form.

Now the problem I'm having is storing that data to appropriate data types so that I'm able to make a pandas data frame from within the flask app on those values and finally run the model.

For example, take three columns - `Age, TravelProfile, EducationField`. `Age` takes in a numeric input, `TravelProfile` takes in input from a drop down menu - 1 for 'Yes', 0 for 'Rarely' and `EducationField` is a categorical that takes in 4 values from a drop down and this needs to be converted to a dummy variable in the final dataset. Although I've been able to define the appropriate values, the HTML form is saving everything as string. This is problematic when converting relevant values through int() because it does not read a list within a string.

```py
from flask, import Flask, request, render_template

@app.route('/', method=["POST"])
def print_dat():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    return render_template("some.html", out=data)
```

What I want is that the form should save data to a proper python dict:

```
{'Age': [56], 'TravelProfile': [1], 'EducationField': ["MBA"]}
```

But what I'm getting is this, even when defining which values I want in the HTML code:

```html
{'Age': '[56]', 'TravelProfile': '[1]', 'EducationField': '["MBA"]'}


# Skipping only to relevant code
<label for="Age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="myTextBox1" name="Age">
    <br>
    <br>
<label for="TravelProfile">Travel Profile</label>
    <select id="myTextBox1" name="TravelProfile">
        <option></option>
        <option value=[0]>Rarely</option>
        <option value=[1]>Yes</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
<label for="EducationField">Education</label>
    <select id="myTextBox1" name="EducationField">
        <option></option>
        <option value=["Statistics"]>Statistics</option>
        <option value=["Marketing Diploma"]>Marketing Diploma</option>
        <option value=["Engineer"]>Engineer</option>
        <option value=["MBA"]>MBA</option>
        <option value=["Other"]>Other</option>
    </select>
<br>
<br>
```

Is there a way to tell HTML to store the data without the quotes for every value?

Comment: Why the list format?

Comment: So it should be clear, why this comes out as string ```type="text" id="myTextBox1" name="Age"``` change ```type``` and it will be a number

Comment: Under <option> attributes? This is necessary for those values to be recognised as indexes in a pandas data frame.

Comment: @FloLie But can it be saved as a list? Does HTML provide that option?

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: I would try to just fetch the number and add [] in code if needed

Comment: No problem. Will delete thread if no solutions comes in.

Comment: If you also provide the snipped, where the result is used, I am sure someone can point to you a nice and lean solution. Without knowing the code, it is a little cumbersome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233509/discussion-between-flolie-and-shiv-90).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I actually have to log out...

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for your issue

HTML CODE:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function textGen() {
            var text1 = document.getElementById('myTextBox1').value;
            var a = document.getElementById('myTextBox2');
            var text2 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
            var b = document.getElementById('myTextBox3');
            var text3 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(text1, text2, text3);
            $.get('/message', { "Age": text1, "Travel Profile": text2, "Education": text3 }).done(function (data) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += `<p>${data}</p>`;
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
        <div class="container">

            <p>Hi!</p>

        </div>


        <div class="darker" id="text">

        </div>

        <label for="Age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" id="myTextBox1" name="Age">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="TravelProfile">Travel Profile</label>
        <select id="myTextBox2" name="TravelProfile">
            <option></option>
            <option value="0">Rarely</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="EducationField">Education</label>
        <select id="myTextBox3" name="EducationField">
            <option></option>
            <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
            <option value="Marketing Diploma">Marketing Diploma</option>
            <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
            <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="textGen()">Submit</button>


</body>

</html>
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def start():
    return render_template("a.html")


@app.route("/message")
def index():
    Age = request.args.get("Age")
    Tprofile = request.args.get("Travel Profile")
    Education = request.args.get("Education")
    return ("{},{},{}".format(Age,Tprofile,Education))

app.run()
```